# Android Studio Room query to get a random row of db and saving the rows 2nd column in variable

Tags: android-studio, android-room

like the title mentions I want a Query that gets a random row of the existing database. After that I want to save the data which is in a specific column of that row in a variable for further purposes.

The query I have at the moment is as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM data_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
fun getRandomRow()
```

For now I am not sure if this query even works, but how would I go about writing my function to pass a specific column of that randomly selected row to a variable?

Ty for your advice, tips and/or solutions!

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct; however, you should specify a return type in the function signature. For example, if the records in the data_table table are mapped using a data class called DataEntry, then the query could read as shown below (note I've also added the suspend modifier so the query must be run using a coroutine):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM data_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getRandomRow(): DataEntry?
```

If your application interacts with the database via a repository and view model (as described here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) then the relevant methods would be along the lines of:

DataRepository

```
suspend fun findRandomEntry(): DataEntry? = dataEntryDao.getRandomRow()
```

DataViewModel

```
fun getRandomRecord() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val entry: DataEntry? = dataRepository.findRandomEntry()
    entry?.let {
        // You could assign a field of the DataEntry record to a variable here
        // e.g. val name = entry.name
    }
}
```

The above code uses the view model's coroutine scope to query the database via the repository and retrieve a random DataEntry record. Providing the returning DataEntry record is not null (i.e. your database contains data) then you could assign the fields of the DataEntry object to variables in the let block of the getRandomRecord() method.

As a final point, if it's only one field that you need, you could specify this in the database query. For example, imagine the DataEntry data class has a String field called name. You could retrieve this bit of information only and ignore the other fields by restructuring your query as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT name FROM data_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getRandomRow(): String?
```

If you go for the above option, remember to refactor your repository and view model to expect a String instead of a DataEntry object.